# jstree display icon after note label

Tags: jquery-plugins, jstree

How can I put buttons after the note label. The button/icon could be used for displaying a status like online/offlien or something like that. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

{
        "data" : {
            "title" : "Main",
            "attr" : { "href" : "#link" },
            "icon" : "module"
        }
}

in css
.jstree .module {
    background: url(../extensions.png) no-repeat top left !important;
}